# My modal is not updating new data from cookie

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have problem with updating modal with new data from cookie. When I select new item in table and push it to cookie. Then it wan't to update my modal view when i press button.

Can somebody figured out why it's not working.

```
<script>
var selVal = new Array();

$("tbody tr").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        var pId = $(this).find('td:first').data("id"); // Get id num from selected

        //Remove item from array
        var i = selVal.findIndex(x => x.pId === pId);

        if (i !== -1) {
            selVal.splice(i, 1);
        }
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        var pId = $(this).find('td:first').data("id"); // Get id num from selected
        var pNum = $(this).find('td:first').html(); //Get pnum from selected

        var newObjArr = {pId, pNum};

        selVal.push(newObjArr);
    }
    createCookie(selVal);
});

function createCookie(selVal) {

    var json_str = JSON.stringify(selVal); // JSON Serialize

    // Define/Set cookie
    Cookies.set("Cookie_<?php echo $id?>", json_str, {expires: 1});
}
```

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" id="refdata_btn" class="btn btn-info">Refresh</button> 
                <p><label>Airline: </label><input type="text" name='xxxxxx'></p>
                <p><label>Date: </label> <input type='date'></p>

                <?php
                $cookie_name = 'Cookie_' . $id;

                if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {

                    $decjson = json_decode($_COOKIE[$cookie_name], true);

                    foreach ($decjson as $d) {
                        echo '<p>' . $d['pNum'] . '</p>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Cookie not exist';
                }
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id='btn_later' class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Later</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I see this it is not give me espacially logical why not it is reseting or overriding previous data.

Thanks,
ZS

Comment: It's because you are creating a cookie from client side by using jquery and trying to display cookie using PHP which is server side, once it's loaded will not change until page refresh if you want to change on every click then you need to display cookie by jquery itself.

Comment: Use the cookie for starting point (and maybe ending), but while app is active than use the local or session storage.

Comment: Hi Prateik and skobaljic, thanks for answare I was able to think the same. I try to code jquery instead of php